# Headphone's speaker and microphone not working simultaneously?

Tags: microphone, headphones

My Bluetooth headphone's speakers work when connected. Mic works too when connected(tested using an online service) but it doesn't play any sound when mics are connected.

Comment: Do you have a headphones with built-in mic or two standalone devices? To what device are these peripherals connected to (PC, Phone, what OS?)?

Comment: Headphone which have microphone in it. Windows 10 20H2.